# how can I improve this recursive function? without using loops, regular expressions (regex) and other advanced language tools

Tags: javascript

The function determines the number of certain characters in a string.

```
function countSymbolRec(str, symbol, count) {
    if (str[str.length - 1] === symbol) count ++;
    if (str.length === 1) return console.log(count);
    countSymbolRec(str.slice(0, -1), symbol, count);
}
countSymbolRec("lkjkBBSlkl", "B", 0); // 2
```

Comment: What do you consider an improvement? What is not good in your current implementation? What do you consider "advanced"? Why do you consider loops advanced, and recursion not? Is `slice` not advanced? In code comments you write that your function call returns 2, but it returns `undefined`. Is that intended?

Comment: I'm learning. this is a textbook problem. the condition of the task was to do it strictly through recursion.

Comment: only LENGTH can be used in the task.

how can this be done without SLICE ?

Comment: So where is your attempt at doing that? You are asking to improve... but apparently you have no attempt to fulfil this task? What is the problem? NB: your question does not specify clearly what the requirements are.

Comment: This is my implementation

Comment: But you don't follow your own restrictions. Why then did you use `slice` when you already know you shouldn't use it? Can you explain what the problem is for you to align to the requirements? Again, your question does not even mention these restrictions. Please edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid `String::slice()` since that's slow (creates a new string) and pass the index to look the symbol at as an optional parameter:

```js
const countSymbolRec = (str, symbol, from = 0, count = 0) => 
  from === str.length ? count : countSymbolRec(str, symbol, from + 1, count + (str[from] === symbol));

['A AA CCC BBB C A', '_ ASDF AA'].forEach(str => console.log(str, '=>', countSymbolRec(str, 'A')));
```

```
` Chrome/120
-------------------------------------------------------
Alexander   1.00x  |  x1000000  233  242  242  245  273
OP          1.42x  |  x1000000  330  335  336  345  346
-------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
// @benchmark OP
{
function countSymbolRec(str, symbol, count = 0) {
    if (str[str.length - 1] === symbol) count ++;
    if (str.length === 1) return count;
    return countSymbolRec(str.slice(0, -1), symbol, count);
}

['A AA CCC BBB C A', '_ ASDF AA', 'AAAAAAAAAAAA'].map(str =>  countSymbolRec(str, 'A'));
}

// @benchmark Alexander
{
const countSymbolRec = (str, symbol, from = 0, count = 0) => 
  from === str.length ? count : countSymbolRec(str, symbol, from + 1, count + (str[from] === symbol));

['A AA CCC BBB C A', '_ ASDF AA', 'AAAAAAAAAAAA'].map(str =>  countSymbolRec(str, 'A'));
}
/*@end*/eval(atob('e2xldCBlPWRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcigic2NyaXB0Iik7aWYoIWUubWF0Y2hlcygiW2JlbmNobWFya10iKSl7bGV0IHQ9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7dC5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmpzZGVsaXZyLm5ldC9naC9zaWxlbnRtYW50cmEvYmVuY2htYXJrL2xvYWRlci5qcyIsdC5kZWZlcj0hMCxkb2N1bWVudC5oZWFkLmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKHQpfX0='));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `indexOf`!

```js
function countSymbolRec(str, symbol, index) {
  // Starting at `index`, find the first occurrence of `symbol` in `str`
  const symbolIndex = str.indexOf(symbol, index)
  // If `str` does not contain `symbol`, return no matches
  if (symbolIndex === -1) {
      return 0
  }
  // Otherwise, go to the next index and search again with an incremented count
  return 1 + countSymbolRec(str, symbol, symbolIndex+1)
}
console.log(countSymbolRec("lkjkBBSlkl", "B", 0)); // 2
```

This has the advantage that the recursion stack will have the same number of layers as the number of occurrences of `symbol` on `str`.

On the other hand, your implementation's recursion stack will contain the same number of layers as the length of `str`.

Compare these:

- on the best case, a `str` of length *L* will not contain any instances of `symbol`. Your implementation will have a recursion stack size of *L*, while this solution will have a size of 1
- on the average case, a `str` of length *L* will contain *L/2* instances of `symbol`. Your implementation will have a recursion stack size of *L*, while this solution will have a size of *L/2*
- on the worst case, a `str` of length *L* will be composed of only `symbol` characters. Both your implementation and this solution will have a recursion stack size of *L*

So in most cases, the stack size of this solution is smaller than yours. This is a great improvement, specially for large strings.

Comment: You could remove `count` from the parameter list, and instead have `return 1 + countSymbolRec(str, symbol, symbolIndex+1)`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @enzo's answer: you can use an internal recursive function

```js
function countSymbolRec(str, symbol) {
  const counter = (str, cnt = 0) => !str.includes(symbol)
      ? cnt
      : counter(str.slice(str.indexOf(symbol) + 1), cnt + 1);
  return counter(str.slice(str.indexOf(symbol)));
}

// with a slight adaption, you can count
// single characters OR substrings
function countWords(str, word) {
  const counter = (str, cnt = 0) => !str.includes(word)
      ? cnt
      : counter(str.slice(str.indexOf(word) + word.length), cnt + 1);
  return counter(str.slice(str.indexOf(word)));
}

console.log(`countSymbolRec("lkjkBBSlkl", "B") => ${
  countSymbolRec("lkjkBBSlkl", "B")}`);
console.log(`countSymbolRec("lkjCCkSlkl", "B") => ${
  countSymbolRec("lkjCCkSlkl", "B")}`);

console.log(`countWords("lkj BBBk SlkBBBl", " BB") => ${
  countWords("lkj BBBk Slk BBBl", "Bk")}`);
console.log(`countWords("lkjkBBSlkl", "B") => ${
  countWords("lkjkBBSlkl", "B")}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

A general pattern for recursive loops is as follows:

```
if the input is empty, terminate
split the input into "head" (=first item) and "tail" (=rest)
do something with the "head"
apply the recursion to the "tail"
```

In your case:

```js
function count(str, s) {
    if (str.length === 0)
        return 0
    let [head, ...tail] = str
    return (head === s) + count(tail, s)
}

console.log(count("AbcAxy", "A"))
```

or, if you want the function to be tail-recursive

```js
function count(str, s, res) {
    if (str.length === 0)
        return res
    let [head, ...tail] = str
    return count(tail, s, res + (head === s))
}


console.log(count("AbcAxy", "A", 0))
```

Comment: I am very grateful to you! Very informative!

Comment: @yalanday, if this is what you need, please mark the answer as accepted.